# How to get only the maximum values of a joined table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have **items** that can have many **prices**. I want a **result table** that has all the **items** itself **and only the latest price** of the **item** for a given region.

**item**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | banana |
| 2 | apple |

​

**price**

| id | item_id | region | price | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | USA | 10 | 1-1-2021 |
| 2 | 1 | USA | 20 | 2-1-2021 |
| 3 | 2 | USA | 30 | 1-1-2021 |
| 4 | 2 | Canada | 40 | 2-1-2021 |

​

**result** (should look like this)

| id | name | region | price | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | banana | USA | 20 | 2-1-2021 |
| 2 | apple | USA | 30 | 1-1-2021 |

I tried this but it returns all the rows from both tables.

```
select *
from item
LEFT JOIN price p on p.item_id = item.id
where p.created_at in (
    select max(price.created_at) 
    from price 
    where p.id = price.id
)
and p.region = 'USA'
```

​

I fail to understand what I have to do to reduce the result table to only the rcords with the latest prices for each item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id, i.name, p.region, p.price, p.date
FROM price p 
INNER JOIN (SELECT item_id, MAX(date) AS date FROM price GROUP BY item_id) t 
ON t.item_id = p.item_id AND t.date = p.date
JOIN item i 
ON p.item_id = i.id 
WHERE p.region = 'USA'
```

Part of the reason your code did not work is that, in your WHERE clause, you are filtering by the maximum date of all the records in the **price** table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical use-case for `row_number()`:

```
select *
from item i left join
     (select p.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id order by created_at desc) as seqnum
      from price p 
      where p.region = 'USA'
     ) p
     on p.item_id = i.id and seqnum = 1;
```